# Inplace array modification in Haskell?

Tags: arrays, haskell, optimization, ghc

We all know that modifying a member of a list in a functional style is pretty slow (O(n) for vector, O(log n) for trees), so is there an optimization in the ghc compiler which optimizes this operation to in-place modification? If so, what circumstances does it need? Does it work if the modification happens in a function, and the list you want to modify is one of its arguments?

Comment: You can make use of a *mutable array* (https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/stm-2.5.0.0/Control-Concurrent-STM-TArray.html) for example in an `STM` monad.

Comment: Is there a way that ghc optimizes the code automatically?

Comment: In ancient times, we had `Data.Array.Diff` which was a pure array implementation with O(1) access and update. The catch was that when you updated an array using `let new = old // [(index,value)]` accessing `old` became slower. Essentially, after N updates, accessing the newest array costed O(1), while the oldest copy costed O(N). The implementation under the hood used mutation to redefine the older copies as the newest plus some "difference", so to have a pure interface. This was removed from the libraries at some point. We now use mutable vectors, when needed.

Answer (score 4):

No, the compiler does not detect “modification” of pure data structures, turning them into an in-place modification. If you really need the performance characteristics of mutable arrays, you have to use them explicitly (as Willem mentions in the comment).

Comment: arguably, [it should](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array). if the array is a loop variable, linearity is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure that *O(log n)* is that slow. In fact *O(log n)* is frequently seen as "fast". Most database indexes use [*B-tree*s [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) or similar datastructures. Although most databases do not update the trees in a functional-like style, the time complexity to insert, retrieve, update, remove, etc. are *O(log n)* as well. Unless the amount of data really scales gigantic, *O(log n)*, is likely sufficient, given of course the algorithm is implemented reasonably well.

A popular package that is shipped with most distributions is [**`array`** [hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array/) that allows fast editing of arrays. It makes use of an `IO` or `ST` monad such that "outside" the container it is still pure, while under the hood it of course makes modifications to the array.

The [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Arrays#Mutable_arrays_in_ST_monad_.28module_Data.Array.ST.29) has an example on an `ST` array. Here we make :

> ```
> buildPair :: ST s (Integer, Integer)
> buildPair = do
>     arr <- newArray (1,10) 37 :: ST s (STArray s Int Integer)
>     a <- readArray arr 1
>     writeArray arr 1 64
>     b <- readArray arr 1
>     return (a,b)
> ```

Here we thus first make an array with bounds `(1,10)` and we initialize all elements with `37`. Next we read the value on the first line, then we change it to 64, and then we read the value again.

Note that the `ST s (Integer, Integer)` itself does *not* make modifications, you can see it as a recipe to obtain a 2-tuple `(Integer, Integer)`. If we then use [`runST :: (forall s . ST s a) -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html#v:runST) we will run the recipe and thus produce the result.

For example:

```
Prelude Control.Monad Control.Monad.ST Data.Array.ST> runST buildPair
(37,64)
```